# Python 2.7 - Accepting multiple lines through a txt file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Someone gave me this code to try to fix, (pig latin) I've got it to accept one line through a txt file, but when I add more lines in the txt file it breaks. With index error. Any of you know what my problem is?

```
vowels = ("A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u")



# Functions

text = raw_input("Enter the path of a text file: ")
def pig_word(string):
    for line in text:
        line = line.split()
    lines = []
    for line in string.split('\n'):
        new_string = ""
        for word in line.split(" "):
            first_letter = word[0]
            if first_letter in vowels:
                 new_string += word + "way" + " "
            else:
                 new_string += word[1:] + first_letter + "ay" + " "
                 global new_string
            lines.append(new_string)



def line_counter(s):
    line_count = 0
    for _ in s.split("\n"):
        line_count += 1
    return line_count

def word_counter(line):
    word_count = 0
    list_of_words = line.split()
    word_count += len(list_of_words)
    return word_count

# File path conversion

file_path = open(text, "r")
out_file = open("pig_output.txt", "w")


s = file_path.read()
pig = pig_word(s)
out_file.write(str(new_string)+ "\n")
out_file.write("\n")


linecount = line_counter(s)
wordcount = word_counter(s)


file_path.close()
out_file.close()

# Results

print "\n\n\n\nTranslation finished and written to pig_output.txt"
print "A total of {} lines were translated successfully.".format(linecount)
print "A total of {} words were translated successfully.".format(wordcount)
print "\n\n\n\n"
```

Error is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.MU-L-ZB046882H/Desktop/Code/chal.py", line 42, in <module>
    pig = pig_word(s)
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.MU-L-ZB046882H/Desktop/Code/chal.py", line 13, in pig_word
    first_letter = word[0]
IndexError: string index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Looks like someone gave you a homework. Good. It would help, if you provide exact error message, it often contains a lot of usefull information (like exact instruction, line of code, etc.)

Comment: Oh, forgot to add that thanks!, Don't know if it's homework or not. Just a challenge someone gave me.

Comment: Was that person the asker of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36666848/2564301)?

Comment: The error message doesn't match the code.  There is no `first_letter = lines[0]`.

Comment: Would that I could purge the `global` statement from Python.  It does an enormous disservice to beginners.

Comment: @MarkTolonen ah, my bad, when I was changing code around must of accidentally replaced it, fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error shows, that you are trying to access first letter from empty string.

The case could be your usage of `.split` using explicitly `" "`.

If you take for example a line with few spaces and split it by `" "`, you get couple of empty string:

```
>>> line = "     "
>>> line.split(" ")
['', '', '', '', '', '']
```

May be you have better to split using default blanks space delimiter:

```
>>> line.split()
[]
```

Comment: Using that method, I then get the error: File "C:/Users/Administrator.MU-L-ZB046882H/Desktop/Code/chal.py", line 42, in <module>
    pig = pig_word(s)
  File "C:/Users/Administrator.MU-L-ZB046882H/Desktop/Code/chal.py", line 12, in pig_word
    for word in line.split:
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable

Comment: @PaulB1234 It is likely, that my answer will fix one particular problem and you will run into another one. Mind, that StackOverflow shall focus on specific problem. Questions in style "fix my code" are considered too wide. If you do not manage fixing next error which will come, create new question. But best if you manage fixing yourself - you will learn and gain the most from it.

Comment: @PaulB1234 Looks like you forgot to use `()` after `split`. Even using no argument in function call require `()`.

Comment: Thanks. My bad. Now it isn't writing back to the file.

Comment: @PaulB1234, there are a lot of errors in the file.  Learn to use a debugger.  `python -m pdb program.py` or use IDLE's debugger.  There are many others.

Answer (score 0):

'new_string += word[1:] + first_letter + "ay" + " " '
This line could do an index out of range exception if the word only has one letter like 'a' ;)

And I agree with the comment that your global statement is confusing and an error source - just an advice for better style ;)

Comment: Hey, the actual file doesn't include just one letter in a line. is pig latin good
or 
is it
bad
is in the file